# Is using shared_ptr and weak_ptr to manage lifetime of std::function safe?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, shared-ptr, boost-thread, std-function

I've created a wrapper around boost::asio::io_service to handle asynchronous tasks on the GUI thread of an OpenGL application.

Tasks might be created from other threads so `boost::asio` seems ideal for this purpose and means I don't need to write my own task queue with associated mutexes and locking. I want to keep the work done on each frame below an acceptable threshold (e.g. 5ms) so I'm calling `poll_one` until the desired budget is exceeded, rather than calling `run`. As far as I can tell this requires me to call `reset` whenever new tasks are posted, which seems to be working well.

Since it's short, here's the whole thing, sans `#include`:

```cpp
typedef std::function<void(void)> VoidFunc;
typedef std::shared_ptr<class UiTaskQueue> UiTaskQueueRef;

class UiTaskQueue {

public:

    static UiTaskQueueRef create()
    {
        return UiTaskQueueRef( new UiTaskQueue() );
    }

    ~UiTaskQueue() {} 

    // normally just hand off the results of std/boost::bind to this function:
    void pushTask( VoidFunc f )
    {
        mService.post( f );
        mService.reset();
    }

    // called from UI thread; defaults to ~5ms budget (but always does one call)        
    void update( const float &budgetSeconds = 0.005f )
    {
        // getElapsedSeconds is a utility function from the GUI lib I'm using
        const float t = getElapsedSeconds();
        while ( mService.poll_one() && getElapsedSeconds() - t < budgetSeconds );
    }

private:

    UiTaskQueue() {}

    boost::asio::io_service mService;
};
```

I keep an instance of UiTaskQueueRef in my main app class and call `mUiTaskQueue->update()` from within my app's animation loop.

I'd like to extend the functionality of this class to allow a task to be canceled. My previous implementation (using almost the same interface) returned a numeric ID for each task and allowed tasks to be canceled using this ID. But now the management of the queue and associated locking is handled by `boost::asio` I'm not sure how best to do this.

I've made an attempt by wrapping any tasks I might want to cancel in a `shared_ptr` and making a wrapper object that stores a `weak_ptr` to the task and implements the `()` operator so it can be passed to the `io_service`. It looks like this:

```
struct CancelableTask {
    CancelableTask( std::weak_ptr<VoidFunc> f ): mFunc(f) {}
    void operator()(void) const {
        std::shared_ptr<VoidFunc> f = mFunc.lock();
        if (f) {
            (*f)();
        }
    }
    std::weak_ptr<VoidFunc> mFunc;
};
```

I then have an overload of my `pushTask` method that looks like this:

```
void pushTask( std::weak_ptr<VoidFunc> f )
{
    mService.post( CancelableTask(f) );
    mService.reset();
}
```

I then post cancelable tasks to the queue using:

```
std::function<void(void)> *task = new std::function<void(void)>( boost::bind(&MyApp::doUiTask, this) );
mTask = std::shared_ptr< std::function<void(void)> >( task );
mUiTaskQueue->pushTask( std::weak_ptr< std::function<void(void)> >( mTask ) );
```

Or with the `VoidFunc` typedef if you prefer:

```
VoidFunc *task = new VoidFunc( std::bind(&MyApp::doUiTask, this) );
mTask = std::shared_ptr<VoidFunc>( task );
mUiTaskQueue->pushTask( std::weak_ptr<VoidFunc>( mTask ) );
```

So long as I keep the `shared_ptr` to `mTask` around then the `io_service` will execute the task. If I call `reset` on `mTask` then the `weak_ptr` can't lock and the task is skipped as desired.

My question is really one of confidence with all these new tools: is `new std::function<void(void)>( std::bind( ... ) )` an OK thing to be doing, and a safe thing to manage with a `shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is safe.

For the code:

```
VoidFunc *task = new VoidFunc( std::bind(&MyApp::doUiTask, this) );
mTask = std::shared_ptr<VoidFunc>( task );
```

Just do:

```
mTask.reset(new VoidFunc( std::bind(&MyApp::doUiTask, this) ) );
```

(and elsewhere).

Bear in mind that you need to deal with the race condition where a tread might be getting a lock on the weak_ptr just before you reset the shared_ptr keeping the callback alive, and as a result you will occasionally see callbacks even though you went down the code path resetting the callback shared_ptr.

Comment: Many thanks! I think I'm able to avoid the race condition by only canceling from the UI thread where the tasks will be processed, but I'll keep it in mind for the threaded version of this code.

Comment: Thanks for the initialization tip too!